# Imported symbol from typescript library is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a React/Redux application using Typescript. In order to simplify development, I want to create libraries for each "domain" or "feature" that will encapsulate specifics of the domain and expose an API to the top-level application.

So far I have created a library (in Typescript) named `@foo/foo` and a main application that depends on this library. The library has a toplevel `index.ts` file that looks like:

```
export * from "./services/Executor";
export * from "./services/Foo";
export * from "./services/Result";
export * from "./services/listFoo";
```

The file `./services/Executor.ts` exports a bunch of functions like:

```
export const fetchFoo = ...
```

Then I created an application using `create-react-app --script react-ts` and in one of the actions file I do:

```
import { fetchFoo } from '@foo/foo';
...
```

But when I run the React application using `npm run start`, I got:

> TypeError: fetchFoo is not a function

From my research on the web I assume I am messing up with modules import semantics: Both packages are configured (in `tsconfig.json`) to be compiled to `es6` with `esModuleInterop: true`. I tried changing `modules` field but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Here is some code demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/abailly/react-ts-import-module

Comment: Have you set your `module` to `commonjs`?

Comment: Where? In `lib/` yes

Comment: in `tsconfig.json/compilerOptions`

Comment: In the `app/tsconfig.json`?

Comment: In `@foo/foo` tsconfig.json

Comment: Yes, I did set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference your build output under the "main" key in your package.json and point to the main declaration file under the "types" key:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

CRAs tsc/webpack will look for a JS file when bundling. Imported modules are not transpiled by default (though this could be enabled, but since you build your lib separately this should not be necessary)

I hope that works (and helps if yes ;)

Comment: Yeah, that did it! Many thanks, I owe you a beer next time you come to Nantes :) But I must say I am impressed by how fragile this whole ecosystem of js/ts is...